# theme of this specific beamer theme

Tags: beamer, presentations, themes

Someone could tell me the name of the beamer theme usedhere ? it looks a lot like Warsaw.
 
[image]

[image]

Also, I would like to know how to have the email address just below the name. And the name of the supervisor right below them.
Thank

Comment: Please do not ask multiple questions in a single question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it is the `Copenhagen` theme with a different primary colour. The missing separation on the left of the footline makes me believe it is a user defined footline. (The following example need beamer version >= 3.48)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\author{names}
\title{text}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=blue}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\hfill\insertshortdate\quad\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{title}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]